# Opening a file within my app using one of the pre-installed programs

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-file

I had searched through different questions here but still didn't get how to approach it.

So, basically, I have a file in my app that is displayed as if in file explorer, consequently, when user clicks on it - i want to open it using preinstalled program. Say, I want to open a pdf file with a  preinstalled pdf viewer. How do I approach this? If there any "automatic" solutions when you just give android a file path and its type and it offers you programs it can be opened with?

Thanks xx

Comment: that is what is called as implicit intent- try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android will appropriate prog to open it if available

```
Intent contacts = new Intent();

 contacts.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

contacts.setData(uri for what u want 2 do);

 startActivity(contacts);
```

Comment: Yeah, you were 5 sec faster than me. I think this is what i am looking for, thanks xx

Comment: Actually i prefer your initial answer :) This might be confusing for some people))

Comment: but its better so he will understand what he is setting in each